# How to make predictions on a sagemaker endpoint? (JSON error)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, prediction, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a sagemaker endpoint and want to run predictions on the endpoint now. The endpoint represents a sagemaker pipeline and model. I followed the tutorial [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/train-register-deploy-pipeline-model/train%20register%20and%20deploy%20a%20pipeline%20model.ipynb). My code to set up the predictor and make the predictions is as follows:

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
predictor = Predictor(endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
data_df = data_df.drop("LABEL_NAME", axis=1)
pred_count = 1
payload = data_df.iloc[:pred_count].to_string(header=False, index=False).replace("  ", ",")
p = predictor.predict(payload, initial_args={"ContentType": "text/csv"})
```

This code is pretty much what they have displayed in the example I linked and it makes sense to me. My preprocess.py code for the pipeline includes the following functions which I am including (although not sure they are relevant):

```
def input_fn(input_data, content_type):
    print("BAHHHHHH")
    if content_type == "text/csv":
        # Read the raw input data as CSV.
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(input_data), header=None)
        return df
    else:
        raise ValueError("{} not supported by script!".format(content_type))

def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    print("BAHHHHHH")
    if accept == "application/json":
        instances = []
        for row in prediction.tolist():
            instances.append(row)
        json_output = {"instances": instances}

        return worker.Response(json.dumps(json_output), mimetype=accept)
    elif accept == "text/csv":
        return worker.Response(encoders.encode(prediction, accept), mimetype=accept)
    else:
        raise RuntimeException("{} accept type is not supported by this script.".format(accept))

def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    print("BAHHHHHH")
    features = model.transform(input_data)
    return features

def model_fn(model_dir):
    print("BAHHHHHH")
    """Deserialize fitted model"""
    preprocessor = joblib.load(os.path.join(model_dir, "model.joblib"))
    return preprocessor
```

When running the predictor.predict() method I get the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
    "error": "JSON Parse error: Missing a comma or ']' after an array element. at offset: 16"
```

I printed out the payload variable right before it was passed to the predict method and it looks like this (I truncated it as it's quite long but this should be enough to see what is is like:

```
0 999.105105 888.607813 6.0 1 los angeles 2431.666667 1.0 NaN 1177.813623 1.076833e+06 los angeles$1$6 0 60376511012 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ............
```

The error message also provides a url to look at for more information. It is the cloud watch logs for the endpoint. looking through these logs I see no extra information, just a 400 error with NO additional information apart from the 400 error.

So there is obviously some issue with the format of the data I am passing in. The input_fn, output_fn, predict_fn and model_fn methods all have a print statements in them at the start of the method but none of these show up in the logs so I don't think any of these are being reached.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you try to set the `serializer` to be CSVSerializer like 
```from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
predictor.serializer = CSVSerializer()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest testing by making sure you can deserialize your payload locally to confirm there is no issue with the the payload and/or code to serialize and load the CSV back into memory.

Also, I suggest testing using a simple payload and note the behavior.